# Use Google Authenticator 2FA in VS Code SSH with Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, debian, google-compute-engine, google-authenticator

My VS Code has a SSH-FS connection with my GCE VM and can view / edit files and folder structures directly from the sidebar of VS Code client app in my MacOS. In strengthening the security of my VM, I enabled 2FA to my VM instance by adding metadata of `enable-oslogin-2fa=TRUE` and `enable-oslogin=TRUE`. However, the VS Code SSH, which was working perfectly, now shows an error saying `error while connecting to ssh fs all configured authentication methods failed`. Is there a way to keep my 2FA setting for VM instance while maintaining automatic SSH connection for my VS Code app?

Source of Google 2FA
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/setup-two-factor-authentication#configure_2fa

### Environment

VS Code: Version: 1.52.1
Google Compute Engine VM Instance: Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)

Comment: What I noticed on your error is an authentication error

Comment: Did you consult ['Supported methods or challenge types?'] (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/setup-two-factor-authentication#supported_methods_or_challenge_types) also [granting os login?] (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/setup-two-factor-authentication#configure_users)